# Android – what is Google Play Console pre-Launch-Report error 4000004?

Tags: android

On the play console, rolled out an APK release over 9 hours ago, and cannot find any mention of this APK under Release Management/ Pre-Launch Reports.

Sometimes get the message “an unexpected error occurred.  Please try again later (4000004), and sometimes cannot get into Pre-Launch Reports.

Any ideas what this is?

Answer (score 6):

I contacted Chat, the APK has been published to internal test, but there is an issue with Pre-Launch Reports, it is currently broken and should be fixed next week.

Comment: Thanks, I'm facing the same issue too.

Comment: Hopefully they will fix it soon